# wrap a string with single quotes PHP

Tags: php, mysql, quote

I am building a query and I need to wrap my strings with a `single quote`:

```
$sqlRome.="SELECT distinct id_jeune FROM jeunes_rome WHERE code_rome IN (";
                foreach ($liste_rome as $rome):
                 $sqlRome.="'".$rome."'";//HERE
                    if ($j < count($liste_rome) - 1):
                        $sqlRome.=",";
                   $sqlRome.=") GROUP BY id_jeune HAVING COUNT(*)=" . $j;
```

I did it before, but I can not remember! It must be simple I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with -

```
            $sqlRome.="SELECT distinct id_jeune FROM jeunes_rome WHERE code_rome IN (";
            foreach ($liste_rome as $rome) {
                $var[] = "'".$rome."'";
            }
            $sqlRome.= implode(',', $var);
            $sqlRome.=") GROUP BY id_jeune HAVING COUNT(*)=" . $j;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing that just fine, apart from any potential sql injection problems.

You do have a problem with your block-structure however, use `{ ... }` or end your `foreach ():` and `if ():` statements with the correct block endings:

```
$sqlRome="SELECT distinct id_jeune FROM jeunes_rome WHERE code_rome IN (";
//      ^ no concatenation here
foreach ($liste_rome as $rome):
     $sqlRome.="'".$rome."'";//HERE
     if ($j < count($liste_rome) - 1):
           $sqlRome.=",";
     // end the if statement
     endif;
// end the foreach loop
endforeach;
$sqlRome.=") GROUP BY id_jeune HAVING COUNT(*)=" . $j;
```

And where does `$j` come from? As it does not change in the loop, it is either always adding a comma or never. That is probably not what you want.

Comment: the code i posted is a part of a big query,thats why i concate the first time.I also increment the $j.Thank you @jeroen